# Normalizing pixel Values in PyTorch

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I am currently working with the CORnet-Z neural network and I am training it on an alternative version of the ImageNet image dataset.

I looked through the code and noticed this image value normalization method:

```
normalize = torchvision.transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                             std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
...
```

> And then implemented later in the train, val, and test class:

```
torchvision.transforms.Compose([
    torchvision.transforms.RandomResizedCrop(256),
    torchvision.transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
    normalize]))
```

I was wondering if I could rewrite this to just take the RGB pixel values and divide them by 255 to have a scale of 0-1 to work with.

According to the `torchvision.transforms` documentation this is not an implemented approach.

Comment: You can use `torchvision.transforms.Normalize`, no need for a custom function, see below.

Answer (score 1):

What you found in the code is statistics standardization, you're looking to normalize the input. These are two different operations but can be carried out with the same operator: under [`torchvision.transforms`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html) by the name of [`Normalize`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.Normalize). It applies a shift-scale on the input:

> Normalize a tensor image with mean and standard deviation. This transform does not support PIL Image. Given `mean`: `(mean[1],...,mean[n])` and `std`: `(std[1],..,std[n])` for `n` channels, this transform will normalize each channel of the input `torch.*Tensor` *i.e.*, `output[channel] = (input[channel] - mean[channel]) / std[channel]`.

```
>>> normalize = T.Normalize(mean=0, std=255)
```

Your transformation pipeline is then:

```
>>> T.Compose([T.RandomResizedCrop(256),
               T.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
               T.ToTensor(),
               normalize]))
```

*where `torchvivision.transforms` is imported as `T`*.

Comment: This implementation results the network not learning i.e the accurcay does not increase above chance

Comment: Having a code that runs and a model that learns are two very different things. All three answers provided here implement the function you are looking for. The issue with your model not learning, I'm afraid, is another problem!

Comment: Do you know why this could be? With the current normalize (seen in the question) it learns, but with the other implementations it does not learn at all. Could it be something about the torchvision.transform function?

Comment: You need to keep those values provided by the dataset, these are the statistics that were measured from the training set. Did you actually check the range of your values on the output of the transform?

Comment: @legomi1 This is a general concept of "data normalization in Machine Learning" (can read up on that for intuition). (Much of) ML is about fitting functions to produce desired outputs. Normalizing the data sometimes can help get a better fit.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a lambda? (corrected to use `transforms.Lambda`)

```py
data_transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Lambda(lambda t: t/255)  # Scale pixel values to 0..1
    ])
```

Comment: implementing this, I get an AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'ImageNetTrain.data.<locals>.<lambda>'

Comment: Right. Corrected to wrap it with transforms.Lambda

Answer (score -1):

You will have to write a custom transform. If you want to divide each pixel by 255 you can do below:

```
import torch
from torchvision import transforms, datasets
import numpy as np

# Custom Trranform
class custom_normalize(object):
    def __init__(self, n):
      self.n = n

    def __call__(self, tensor):        
        return tensor/self.n

data_transform = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        custom_normalize(255)
    ])

# Some dummy data
x_images = np.random.randint(0,255, size=(4,4,3)).astype(np.float32)
data_transform(x_images)
```

output:

```
tensor([[[0.5922, 0.6275, 0.3098, 0.9765],
         [0.0235, 0.3098, 0.0510, 0.9686],
         [0.0275, 0.0706, 0.4275, 0.2863],
         [0.4275, 0.6196, 0.1843, 0.7333]],

        [[0.2235, 0.8000, 0.1647, 0.5608],
         [0.2941, 0.7412, 0.8275, 0.0706],
         [0.3765, 0.5804, 0.8196, 0.6902],
         [0.0000, 0.8784, 0.0353, 0.2941]],

        [[0.4157, 0.1294, 0.4745, 0.4275],
         [0.0902, 0.9882, 0.7137, 0.9255],
         [0.7725, 0.2824, 0.2314, 0.4353],
         [0.7451, 0.0235, 0.1725, 0.6745]]])
```

Comment: If I implement this code into the existing torchvision.transform.Compose([..., custom_normalize]) it does not throw an error but it does not learn i.e. the accuracy remains at chance level. Should I expect an error with my implementation approach?

Comment: @legomi1 Probably has nothing to do with the suggested transform implemenation. Check your training code for errors.

Comment: @legomi1 the transforms are data manipulation methods and they do not have any learnable weights.